# How can I verify the SHA256 hash of 0.10.3 “Wolfram Warptangent” on Windows?

Tags: cryptography, windows, hash-verification

How can I verify the SHA256 [hash published](https://getmonero.org/downloads/hashes.txt) for the official 0.10.3 release matches the file that I [downloaded](https://getmonero.org/downloads/) for Windows, 64-bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows also has a [built-in command-line tool](https://superuser.com/a/898377/602710) to check hashes.

First, using Windows Explorer, navigate to the folder to which you downloaded `monero-win-x64-v0.10.3.0.zip`.

Then, `shift + right-click` somewhere on the background (don't select any files) and select `Open command window here`.

You'll be presented with the console which will start in the same working folder so it'll make the following steps easier.

Then, command:

```
certutil -hashfile monero-win-x64-v0.10.3.0.zip SHA256
```

You'll see an output like:

```
SHA256 hash of file monero-win-x64-v0.10.3.0.zip:
37 a5 7d 1b e8 1b 61 19 ac 06 d3 f6 37 b4 c5 6f c6 25 f3 e7 90 f3 49 1c 1b dc a4 d6 29 02 bf 13
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

which you can compare against the one published on getmonero.org

Answer (score 2):

Download and install the [Quick Hash GUI](http://quickhash-gui.org/)

Open the program, select `SHA256` then select `file` and find `monero-win-x64-v0.10.3.0.zip` in your downloads folder
If you receive the following output you will know that the hash matches the [GPG signed message](https://getmonero.org/downloads/hashes.txt) listing the correct SHA256 sums

> 37a57d1be81b6119ac06d3f637b4c56fc625f3e790f3491c1bdca4d62902bf13

Answer (score 2):

With Powershell [Get-FileHash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash) cmdlet:

```
PS> Get-FileHash monero-win-x64-v0.10.3.0.zip -Algorithm SHA256
```

The full check could be:

```
PS> '37a57d1be81b6119ac06d3f637b4c56fc625f3e790f3491c1bdca4d62902bf13' -eq 
>> (Get-FileHash monero-win-x64-v0.10.3.0.zip -Algorithm SHA256 | 
>> Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash)
```